# Why should I use optional chaining again after checking the variable is not nil?

Tags: swift

```
class LinkedList : NSObject
{
    var head : Node?
    var tail : Node?

    func insertAtHead( newNode : Node )
    {
        if (head != nil) {
            newNode.next = head
            head?.prev = newNode
            head = newNode
        }
        else {
            head = newNode
        }
    }
}
```

And my node class is:

```
class Node : NSObject
{
    var value : Int = 0
    var next : Node?
    var prev : Node?
}
```

My confusion is about the line `head?.prev = newNode` inside insertAtHead method. I already checked and confirmed that the head is not nil, why can't I just type `head.prev = newNode` in that case? Why should I use optional chaining?

Comment: Your `Node` class causes a strong retain cycle and thus a memory leak. It also has no reason to inherit from `NSObject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't, this is a common Swift anti pattern. Try this instead:

```
class LinkedList {
    var head: Node?
    var tail: Node?

    func insertAtHead(newNode: Node) {
        if let head = head {
            newNode.next = head
            head.prev = newNode
        }

        head = newNode
    }
}
```

Simply comparing to `nil` doesn't do anything about the Optionality of `head`. You still have to unwrap it, one way or another. One way to check for nil and (simultaneously) unwrap it is to use a conditional binding like shown above.

A few other points:

- The `head = newNode` occurs unconditionally in both the "then" and the "else" of the if statement. Thus, it can just be extracted out, and removing the need for the `else` block.
- There is no reason why this class should be inheriting from `NSObject`.

Answer (score 1):

`head` is still optional. It is possible it can become `nil` between the `if` statement and your next reference.

The proper solution is to safely unwrap the optional:

```
func insertAtHead( newNode : Node )
{
    if let thead = head {
        newNode.next = thead
        thead.prev = newNode
        self.head = newNode
    } else {
        head = newNode
    }
}
```

I used a different variable name to make it clear. You can actually do it this way:

```
func insertAtHead( newNode : Node )
{
    if let head = head {
        // head in here is actually a new variable (with the same name)
        newNode.next = head
        head.prev = newNode
        self.head = newNode
    } else {
        head = newNode
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, but I cannot mutate thead inside if let block, because thead is a let constant.

Comment: @sashankaryal Right. Updated. You need to use `self.head = ...` to reference the property.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have check that `head` is not nil, the variable `head` is still optional, so you have to unwrap it using `?`. If you write in the following case, the unwrapped value will be non-optional and you no need to use `?`:

```
func insertAtHead( newNode : Node )
{
    if let head = head {
        newNode.next = head
        head.prev = newNode
        head = newNode
    }
    else {
        head = newNode
    }
}
```